# Interpretation of two handwritten Kurrent words

Tags: meaning-in-context, kurrent

I am currently transcribing a letter of 2 May 1892 [image]from Professor of Philosophy Marcus Jacob Monrad (1816-97) in Christiania (Oslo) to the German translator, i.a. of Ibsen, Louis/Ludwig Passarge.
However, I have problems with interpreting two different words, below marked with XXX. I would greatly appreciate two suggestions!:

(1)
Darum kann ich mir auch nicht den Gedan-
ken aneignen, daß Shakespeare wesentlich
Pessimist sei.  Er hat scharfen Sinn für die
Schattenseiten des Lebens, und weiß diese drastisch
zu schildern, aber er vermag doch
immer selbst über die tiefste Finsterniß
einen Schimmer der Idealität und Hoffnung aus-
zubreiten, und selbst für das ärnste XXX
— eine Richard III z. B. — eine Art von Sym-
pathie zu erwecken.  Ja ich glaube, daß
ich in einen shakespearischen Hölle mich
wohler befinden würde, als in der irdischen
Welt, wie sie Ibsen in den Gengangere
oder im Vildanden schildert.  Selbst das
Böse hat seine poetische Schönheit, die
Fauleste aber keine.

(2)
[image]
..., theils weil in jenen lyri-
schen Ergüßen aus einer früheren Zeit der
Modergeruch noch kaum kenntlich ist
oder doch wie ein pikantes Ess-bouquet, oder
ein haut-goût beim WildXXX den Genuß
nur erhöht,

Comment: You received many answers to your questions. I think they deserve to be accepted. See https://german.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer.

Answer (score 3):

The second word is definitely **Wildpret**, an alternative (antiquated) form of "Wildbret", i.e. venison, the meat of game animals. (Also see the first sentence of the German Wikipedia article for ["Hautgout"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautgout).)

I submit that the first word is [**Scheusal**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Scheusal), though I'm not completely sure (some letters are indistinct).

(Das) Scheusal, being a neuter, fits the sentence (note that the phrase should read "das *ärgste* Scheusal", not "*ärnste*"). And it doubtlessly fits the type of (Shakespeare's) Richard the Third, a "most terrible monster" if there ever was one.

Comment: "Scheusal" makes indeed good sense and is easily compatible with the handwriting. A good example of "native" interpretation being easier than a "foreign" interpretation. Thank you for your excellent help at this occasion ans previously!